# Strange behavior when modifying array in for-loop

Tags: arrays, for-loop, julia

take a look at this example:

```
julia> VERSION
v"0.4.0-rc1"

julia> foo = [1,2]
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2

julia> baz = Array(Any,3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> for i = 1:3
           foo[1] = -foo[1]
           baz[i] = foo
           println("loop",i)
           println("foo: ",typeof(foo),"->",foo)
           println("baz[",i,"]: ",typeof(baz[i]), "->", baz[i])
           println("baz: ",typeof(baz),"->",baz)
       end

loop1
foo: Array{Int64,1}->[-1,2]
baz[1]: Array{Int64,1}->[-1,2]
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[[-1,2],#undef,#undef]
loop2
foo: Array{Int64,1}->[1,2]
baz[2]: Array{Int64,1}->[1,2]
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[[1,2],[1,2],#undef]
loop3
foo: Array{Int64,1}->[-1,2]
baz[3]: Array{Int64,1}->[-1,2]
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[[-1,2],[-1,2],[-1,2]]
```

the results are unexpected to me, i think `baz` should be `Any[[-1,2],[1,2],[-1,2]]`.

However, if `foo` is not an array, the results are reasonable.

```
julia> foo = 1
1

julia> baz = Array(Any,3)
3-element Array{Any,1}:
 #undef
 #undef
 #undef

julia> for i = 1:3
           foo = -foo
           baz[i] = foo
           println("loop",i)
           println("foo: ",typeof(foo),"->",foo)
           println("baz[",i,"]: ",typeof(baz[i]), "->", baz[i])
           println("baz: ",typeof(baz),"->",baz)
       end
loop1
foo: Int64->-1
baz[1]: Int64->-1
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[-1,#undef,#undef]
loop2
foo: Int64->1
baz[2]: Int64->1
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[-1,1,#undef]
loop3
foo: Int64->-1
baz[3]: Int64->-1
baz: Array{Any,1}->Any[-1,1,-1]
```

my question is what happened here, what's the correct way to assign array in for-loop?

EDIT: i added `baz = deepcopy(baz)` and everything goes fine. still want to know the reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julia has [Noteworthy Differences from other Languages](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/noteworthy-differences/) 
e.g. unlike MATLAB Julia arrays are assigned by reference. A reference is an alias, or an alternate name to an existing variable. For example, suppose you make peter a reference (alias) to paul, you can refer to the person as either peter or paul.
After `baz[i] = foo`, changing elements of `foo` will modify `baz[i]` as well.

Comment: so the correct way is to use `deepcopy`, in this case `baz[i] = deepcopy(foo)`, for "decoupling". that makes sense, many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is a common trap, that arises becauses the array `foo` is a *binding*. John Myles White has written a very nice blog post on this:
http://www.johnmyleswhite.com/notebook/2014/09/06/values-vs-bindings-the-map-is-not-the-territory/

By the way, you should try to avoid `Any` arrays, which are slow. You can do this easily as follows:

```
Array(typeof(v), 3)
```

or just put the explicit type of `v`, e.g.

```
Array(Vector{Int}, 3)
```

Here, `Vector{Int}` is equivalent to (another name for) `Array{Int, 1}`.

Also note that instead of all those `println`s, you can just use the nice `@show`:

```
julia> a = 3
3

julia> @show a
a = 3
3
```

`@show` also returns the value shown. On previous versions of Julia, the output looked like `a => 3`

Comment: the material is really, really helpful, thank you for your useful tips!